# how to make changes in .bashrc effective in current terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have an open terminal in ubuntu lucid in which I need a new env variable set.So,I open the .bashrc file and edit it ,to add the new env variable( say PYTHONPATH)

.bashrc

```
PYTHONPATH=/some/path
export PYTHONPATH
```

But,in order to get this effective ,I need to close my terminal and open it again.Is there some command with which I can get this effect,without close/open the terminal again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at the `source` command: `man source`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Apart from that: why don't you simply use the environment commands directly in your shell to set an additional environment variable?

```
export PYTHONPATH="/some/path"
```

That way the created variable is effective right away.

Comment: thanks @arkascha ,learned something good today.. you are right .it can be done in both ways

Answer (score 1):

You can also try,

```
sat:~# . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: `.` is POSIX-compliant, `source` is not. This should be the accepted and most-upvoted answer  :)